# Find all folders with rwx permissions for a certain user?

Tags: terminal, mac, macos, folders, python

How do I find all the folders that have `rwx` permissions for a certain user?

Preferably no admin, can use shell scripts, Terminal, Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

`find "$DIR" -user "$WHO" -type d -perm +777 -print`

where `"$DIR"` is the parent directory that you want to begin searching in, and `"$WHO"` is the username or user-id that you want to look for.

Use `"$LOGNAME"`, `"$USER"`, or `"$UID"` in place of `"$WHO"` to search for the current user.